# Pressing Ctrl+a after clicking a row in the table selects the entire text on the webpage, when using IEDriverServer in Selenium. Why?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer-11

Doing the same using ChromeDriver, selects all the rows. However, I want to select all the rows in the table using IEDriverServer only because the website works without any error only in Internet Explorer.

I'm using IEDriverServer_Win32_3.9.0 and selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar in my Java 8 program. I've tried "setNativeEvents" as true and false, but it doesn't work.

CODE:

```java
//selecting 1st row

element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"T536871013\"]/tbody/tr[2]"));
action.click(element).perform();

//selecting all rows        

action.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys(String.valueOf('a')).perform();

//deselecting 1st row

Thread.sleep(5000);
action.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).click(element).perform();

//reselecting 1st row

Thread.sleep(5000);
action.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).click(element).perform();
```

For some reason, I've to deselect and then reselect any row after 'Ctrl+a' to make the button which I've to click interactable. But that shouldn't be the cause of unwanted behavior in Selenium when using IEDriverServer.
Also, note that pressing "Ctrl+a" manually after clicking the row in IE, selects all the rows just like in does in Chrome. I'm unable to understand why this behavior changes when using IE automation?

And I'm open to suggestion if you have some other workaround to select all the rows in IE.

Edit: I also tried to send 'action.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).click(element).perform()' for every row (represented by 'element') one by one in a loop, and I can see the highlighting over the rows which further confirms that row is discover-able by the driver. This loop again works as expected (selects all the rows one by one) when using ChromeDriver, but when using IEDriverServer, one row is highlighted/selected, then released, then another row is highlighted, then released, and so on..

Comment: When you click on the row manually in IE and then press Ctrl + A, does it select all table rows or the whole page?

Comment: @GregBurghardt It selects all table rows.

Comment: "because the website works without any error only in Internet Explorer" 

Comment: Anyway, you could try to explicitly set the focus to the `element`.

Comment: try to check whether your code able to find correct element using xpath in IE or not? If it is finding incorrect element that it can cause this issue. try to debug the code step by step and check it's effect on web page may help you to narrow down the issue.

Comment: @Holli Can you tell me how to do that? 

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT Yes, it is able to find the correct element, else the code wouldn't have worked using ChromeDriver.

Comment: If the code is working in chrome it does not mean that same code will work exactly with other browser. So it is better to verify from IE that your code is able to find the element in IE.

Comment: Deepak got a point here. add `alert(element);` after the first line. If `element` is defined, call `element.focus();` before you perform the click.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT and Holli Please read "Edit" part in the Question which I just updated.

Comment: Two very important things. First, 3.9 is a relatively old version of the IE driver; the latest is 3.150.0. Second, you haven’t indicated whether you’ve tried the `requireWindowFocus` capability when creating the driver instance. That capability causes the driver to simulate keystrokes in a [completely different way](http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.com/2013/01/revisiting-native-events-in-ie-driver.html), which may be more accurate.

Comment: Is there any chance of updating to the latest version of IE driver server? If yes, than you can do it for testing purpose to check whether it makes any difference or not and let us know about the testing results.

Comment: @JimEvans & Deepak-MSFT If I use the latest version of IEDriverServer, some buttons become uninteractable. I have tried setting requireWindowFocus as true but it didn't work. Also, if I set setNativeEvents as true, every character sent is entered twice in the textbox. I also tried everything mentioned in the comments by different people. Nothing seems to work.

Comment: @JustStartedCoding Then we are at a place where no further assistance can be rendered without access to an HTML page against which your code can be run that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: @JimEvans I can't share the HTML code because I'm not allowed to do that. Thanks everyone for your effort. 